# Apache Rewrite Rule problems

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, dns

I have this url

```
http://keyword.domain.com/ (keyword is any word)
```

And I want to direct it to

```
http://domain.com/keyword
```

How can I do this? I tried

```
Rewriterule http://(.+).domain.com/ http://domain.com/$1
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/%1
```

Comment: Its work.Thank you!! But why can't I use only RewriteRule to achieve it ?

Comment: `RewriteRule` doesn't examine the host header, only the location part of the URL. You have to explicitly tell Apache to examine the host header with the `RewriteCond`. Please mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it.